# Prove that every nonempty subset of real numbers bounded from below has an infinum

Tags: calculus

Prove that every nonempty subset of real numbers bounded from below has an infinum.

[image: two cases]

This is how I attempted to solve this: $Z$ is bounded below, therefore $(\exists m)(\forall z\in Z)(m \le z)$ - I'd like to take into consideration two possible scenarios: (1) $m \in Z$ and (2) $\neg m\in Z$ 
(1) $$(\forall z)(z\ in Z \Rightarrow m \le Z) \Rightarrow m = \inf(Z)$$
(2) If $m$ is not in $z$, then $m \in R \setminus Z$, let's say that $B = R\setminus Z$
Now, we can infer that $B$ has a supremum (Axiom of completeness), therefore $$\exists n \forall b\in B n \ge b$$ Which entails that $$\forall z\in Z n \le z$$
And finally, since $n$ is the greatest element of set $B$, $n = \inf(Z)$
Is this solution to this problem valid? If not, what should I change?

Comment: Um... That's the *definition* of the real numbers.  The question is unanswerable unless I know how you and your text have defined/developed the real numbers.

Comment: @fleablood 
Using field axioms, the axiom of order and the axiom of completeness.

Comment: "Now, we can infer that B has a supremum (Axiom of completeness)"  What's the axiom of completeness say? Have you proven that if a set has the least upper bound property it has the greatest lower bound property?

Comment: State the "axiom of completeness" for me.  I would think the axiom of completeness states just that.

Comment: @fleablood 
No, any hints how to prove that?

Comment: Prove that the supremum of A is equal to the inf of -A.

Comment: Axiom of completeness: 
If a nonempty subset of real numbers is bounded from above, it has a supremum.

Comment: @fleablood, what do you mean by -A? $-A = \{-x : x\in A\}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68250/discussion-between-aemilius-and-fleablood).

Comment: Yes.  If A is bounded below, it's easy to show -A is bounded above.  And if s = sup -A it's easy to show -s = inf A.

Comment: Your statement "$Z$ is bounded " is incorrect. Bounded means bounded above and bounded below. Change it to "$Z$ is bounded below"....

Comment: @fleablood. Nice short-cut. An advantage of the proposer's method is that it applies to any linear order  in which every subset with an  upper bound has a lub..

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That's true.  Maybe I should play it out.

Comment: Reading the OP's attempt (which I confess I didn't before) It's good *except* $B= R \setminus Z$  are not nescessarily all points less than $Z$.  It will include *all* points not in $Z$ and unless Z is an infinite connected segment it *will* include points that are larger than some points in Z.

Comment: .. so instead take the set of all lower bounds.

Comment: @fleablood. Yes. You caught an error. I hadn't studied all the details in the Q.  The proposer has the right  idea : The lub of the set of lower bounds for Z is  glb (Z). But  his presentation has flaws.

Comment: Yes.  The OP was trying to construct a set of the x  that are less than all elements of Z.  Had s/he done that it would have worked.  The set though is not $\mathbb R - Z$.  It is $\{x| x \le a$ for all $a\in Z\}$.  Or in other words, the set of lower bounds.  That will work and I don't think the OP has any other errors.  My shortcut, though clever, assumes we are talking of an ordered field where $-a$ exist for all $a$ and not merely an ordered set (where we don't know $-a$ exists) with the lub property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume the axiom of completeness says in so many words that for any set $A$ that is bounded above that $\sup A$ exists.

Okay, so Let $A$ be a set that is bounded below.  Let $-A = \{ -a|a \in A\}$.

Claim:  $-A$ is bounded above.  Prove.  $A$ is bounded below so there is an $M$ so that $a \ge M$ for all $a$ in $A$.  So $-a \le -M$ for all $-a$ in $-A$.  So $-A$ is bounded above.

So by axiom of completeness $s = \sup -A$ exists.

Claim $-s = \inf A$.

Pf:  $s \ge -a$ for all $-a \in -A$ so $-s \le a $ for all $a \in A$ so $-s$ is a lower bound of $A$.  If $k > -s$ then $-k < s$ so $-k$ is not an upper bound of $-A$ so there is a $e \in -A$ so that $-k < e$.  So $k > -e$.  Now $e \in -A$ implies $-e \in A$ so $-k$ is not a lower bound of $A$.  So $-s$ is a greatest lower bound and $-s = \inf A$.

====

In response to a comment, I figure we should do a direct proof for other spaces that may not have the property that for all $a \in X$ then $-a \in X$.

Since $A$ is bounded below it has a lower bound.

Let $B = \{$lower bounds of $A\}$.  (You took $\mathbb R\setminus A$ which was intuitive but not correct.  There may be many points not in $A$ that are larger than some points in $A$.  Only if $A = [k, \infty)$ or $(k\infty)$ would this *not* be true.)

Let $a \in A$.  If $k\in B$ then $k$ is a lower bound of $a$ so $k\le a\in A$.  So $a$ is an upper bound of $B$.

So a supremum of $B$ exists. Let $s \sup B$.

Claim: $s$ is a lower bound of $A$.  If $a \in A$, $a < s$ then $a$ is not an upper bound of $B$ and there is $b \in B$ so that $a <b \le s$. But $b$ is a lower bound of $A$ so that is impossible.  $a \ge s$ for all $a \in A$.  So $s$ is a lower bound of $A$.

Claim $s = \inf A$.  $k > s$ then $k$ $k \not \in B$ so $k$ is not a lowerbound.  So $s$ is the greatest lower bound.  $s = \inf A$.

Comment: Could you explain what $x$ is?

Comment: x is a letter between w and y and often mistyped when an s was meant to be typed.

Comment: @fleablood u have a little mistake in proof) Claim:$-s=inf A$ not $-k$ is not a lower bound of A, but $k$ is not a lower bound of $A$, since $-k$ is not an upper bound of $-A$

Answer (score 0):

let A be a set bounded from below, let K be the set of lower bounds, since K is bounded by an element of A, K has a supremum. If there exists an x in A such that sup(K) >x, then this is a contradiction since x would be a lesser upper bound for K. So for all x in A, sup(K) <=x, making sup(K) a lower bound, and the greatest of the lower bounds by the definition of supremum.